# im runing ubuntu distro on android and firefox shows white all white?

Tags: lxterminal

How do i install a gui for firefox on ubuntu android/vnc? Ive tryed 'mkdir /dev/shm' to no avail, and ive tryed reinstalling 'iceweasel' didn't work also ive installed gnome yet still firefox displays no text or icons and no url input.

Comment: You may find an answer quicker by visiting http://android,stackexchange.com and searching for others with the same issue.

Comment: What Ubuntu distro runs on android?